# Sender object ID in aspx client side event (javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress, client-side

I need help regarding a problem in the following code block:

```
function(s, e) {
    form1.hfRaiseEvent.value = s.ID;
}
```

This function is called when the Client Side Click Event is fired.
By the way i see it, s is the Sender Object while e is the Event Object.
After iterating through the members of the Sender object i found in a forum post,
i saw the .ID member which is supposed to return the id of the sender.

The problem is that the string i get from this is the following:

```
"undefined"
```

No exceptions, just that string.

Some extra info:

1. I also tried e.target.id which was supposed to do the same as s.ID .
   Got the same result though.
2. fhRaiseEvent is a hidden field in which i store the ID of the
       control that raises the event.
3. The control that calls this function when clicked is a Devexpress
       ASPxEditor.

Need some help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code that is creating the ASPxEdit control?

Comment: `<dx:ASPxImage ID="pEditRefreshSum" 
runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/images/mnuLoanMoves.png" IsPng="True" Width="20px" ImageAlign="Middle">
<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
form1.hfRaiseEvent.value = s.ID;
hbtnRaiseEvent.DoClick();
}" />
</dx:ASPxImage>`

Comment: It looks like your sender (`s`) is actually an ASPxImage, not ASPxEdit object.

Comment: ah that was a typo, it's ASPxEditor :/
gonna fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from the Devexpress Team

I can actually use

```
pEditRefreshSum.JSProperties("cpID") = pEditRefreshSum.ID;
```

to set the ID into a custom Property and then get it on

js using the following line:

```
form1.hfRaiseEvent.value = s.cpID;
```

in order to get the ID

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have assigned anything to the ID of the `ASPxEdit`. It is null by default. You have to explicitly assign an ID. The ID property is inherited from *System.Web.Control*. See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx).

Comment: I've assigned an ID (pEditRefreshSum)

P.S. you can also look at the comments under my question, ill paste some markup there.